# How to use More menucontroller in View controller

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

Can Anyone help me, i'm having problem with UIMenucontroller.In here, i have to use two menucontroller in single viewcontroller.
For First menu only "paste",for other menu "copy","select","select all" When i'm using shared menucontroller it affects the other menu.

My code for **first menu**  is as follows:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool
{
    return true
}

override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool
{

  //actions

}

 UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuItems = nil

    let Select: UIMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Select", action: Selector("Select"))
    let SelectAll: UIMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "SelectAll", action: Selector("SelectAll"))
    let Copy: UIMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Copy", action: Selector("Copy"))


    let menu: UIMenuController = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
    menu.menuItems = [Select,SelectAll,Copy]
    menu.setTargetRect(cell.frame, inView: cell.superview!)
    menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
```

and my **second menu** is:

```
 UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuVisible = false
 let paste: UIMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Paste", action: Selector("paste"))

let menu: UIMenuController = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
menu.menuItems = [paste]   
menu.setTargetRect(message_Textfield.frame, inView:   message_Textfield.superview!)
menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
```

**Error:**
In here,in second menu contains unwanted things as [Select,SelectAll,Copy] with [Paste].

How can i resolve this,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Thanks for your answer,But i found solution as follows:

```
override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool
    {

        if(MenuBool == true){
            if action == Selector("Copy") || action == Selector("star") || action == Selector("info") || action == Selector("forward") || action == Selector("Delete")
            {
                print("UIMenuController====>CellMenu")
                UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuVisible = false
                return true
            }
            print("UIMenuController====>Defaultmenu1")
            return false

        }else if MenuBool == false
        {
            print("UIMenuController====>Defaultmenu2")
            return false

        }else{
            print("UIMenuController====>DefaultmenuElse")

            return false
        }
    }
```

In,this manner working fine.

:):):)

Answer (score 0):

You should override `canPerformAction` in a UITextField subclass to disable the item you don't want, then assign each uitextfield you created to the subclass.

For example, disable paste menu item in uimenucontroller：

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if action == "paste:" {
            return false
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let message_Textfield = CustomTextField()
```

Now  `paste` menu item will be disabled for `message_Textfield`